# Getting x and y, knowing the position id and the number of cols and rows

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an array sized NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS. I have a point to an item in the array called ID. I want to determine the x and y coordinate of that item knowing the ID, NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS.

I figure I have to use a combination of modules and divide.

Example

NUM_ROWS 5

NUM_COLS 3

ID 13

x  x  x

x  x  x

x  x  x

x  x  x

13  x  x

Expected X Y value:

x = 5, y = 1

I'm not sure how to get the right numbers using dived and modules operates on the item ID value.

x = 13 / NUM_COLS = 4.33

y = 13 / NUM_ROWS = 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

$x=(\text{ID}-1)/\text{NUM_COLS}+1$

$y=(\text{ID}-1)\%\text{NUM_COLS}+1$

where $/$ is the integer division and $\%$ is the modulo operator.

But it is much easier (especially as a computer scientist) to count the rows, columns and IDs starting from zero. In this case the formula is simply:

$x=\text{ID}/\text{NUM_COLS}$

$y=\text{ID}\%\text{NUM_COLS}$